# pselect() not recognizing the socket having any IO activity

Tags: c++, c, sockets, posix

take for instance the following code snippet, the creation of the socket, listening and acceptance of a new socket works fine.  The non-blocking mode is also working, however the pselect (or even replacing with select) is not recognizing any IO requests ready on the FDset.  so the return value is always 0 (timed out).

I was wondering if I need to set anything else further before going into pselect() so that it recognizes the IO activity.

```
.....
 // Create the socket
        *m_pSockFD = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
        if( *this->m_pSockFD == -1 ){
            throw ....
        }

        // Set the socket address information
        m_pSockAddr->sin_family = AF_INET;
        m_pSockAddr->sin_port =  htons( 6001 );
        m_pSockAddr->sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

        if( bind(*m_pSockFD, (struct sockaddr *) m_pSockAddr, sizeof(*m_pSockAddr) ) != 0 ){
                .....
        }

        // Listen on this socket using a block queue of 5 - default Block Size
        if( listen( *m_pSockFD, 5) != 0 )
                ........


        // change function control to non blocking file descritor for I/O operations
        long fcntlArg;
        if( (fcntlArg = fcntl( *m_pSockFD, F_GETFL, NULL ) ) < 0 ){
               ...........
        }

        fcntlArg |= O_NONBLOCK;
        if( fcntl( *m_pSockFD, F_SETFL, fcntlArg ) <0 ){
              ...........
        }

        //.........

        int newFD = -1;
        socklen_t salen = sizeof(*m_pSockAddr);


        // loop selecting for a I/O operation ready on the file descriptor then go into accept mode
        struct timespec timeOut;
        timeOut.tv_sec = 1;
        timeOut.tv_nsec = 0;

        fd_set fdset;
        FD_SET( *this->m_pSockFD, &fdset );

        while( !m_bShutDownFinished ){

            // TODO pselect is not registering the activity on the socket
            if( pselect( *this->m_pSockFD, &fdset, NULL , NULL , &timeOut,  NULL ) > 0 ){
                cout << "hello client" << endl;
                break;
            }

            // re-initialize the time struct
            timeOut.tv_sec = 1;
            timeOut.tv_nsec = 0;
        }


        // application is shutting down do not try to accept a new socket
        if( m_bShutDownFinished ) return -1;

        newFD = accept(*m_pSockFD, (struct sockaddr *) m_pSockAddr, &salen);
        if( newFD > -1 ){
            ................
        }

        return newFD;
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to re-initialize the fdset parameters before each call to `select()`.

Each of `readfds`, `writefds`, and `exceptfds` is an input/output parameters.  On return, they have been modified to have ones only for the fds that, respectively, are readable, writeable, or have an exceptional condition of some sort.

```
for (;;) {
    fd_set rfds;
    FD_ZERO(&rfds);
    FD_SET(sock, &rfds);
    /* code to set up timeout omitted */
    n = select(sock + 1, &rfds, 0, 0, &timeout);
    /* check n, and if sock is present in rfds */
}
```

The way you've written the code, you'll only detect an incoming connection if it arrives during the very first call to `pselect()`.  Also, given that you're not using the `sigmask` argument of `pselect()`, you might as well just call `select()`.

Comment: The signature of `FD_SET` is `void FD_SET(int fd, fd_set *set);`, parameters are other way around.

Comment: @VL-80 Thanks for pointing out my mistake. I've edited the answer appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

First argument of pselect should be `*this->m_pSockFD + 1`, shouldn't it?

Comment: Thanks, I did change that but unfortunately the return value from pselect is always 0.  meaning the timeout was reached. I played with the value making it larger and smaller but no difference was found.